# Netgear GS752TXS 10gbe

Tags: switch, netgear

I was looking to link up a NAS and a Server via this switch http://support.netgear.com/app/products/model/a_id/19324

Then use it to build out the rest of the network in a small office server cabinet. I want to make sure that I can get all the 10gbe ports on the same network though and it appears that port 51 and 52 are only valid as uplink ports.

Does anyone have experience with this switch and can I configure those ports to just be normal 10gbe ports in Ethernet mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently special about an uplink port.  You can use those ports to connect to switches or to individual servers (or NAS appliances).  The ports can be configured to support VLAN tagging - or, in your case, can be untagged ports in the same VLAN as the 48 GE ports.

Ports 51 and 52 are configurable as either stack ports or uplink (read: normal) ports.  The stacking mode is just a proprietary mechanism to make up to 6 of these switches show up as a single device.  If you buy more of these switches this might be a handy way of growing your network.  If you don't, they're just ports.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was going to try to have the server etc communicate on these ports with a different network address space. Once I just adopted the same address space as all other machines on the network I had no issue making things work. I was mislead a bit when the ports still show up as "detached" in the web interface, however pings work and I am able to mount the NFS shares over these interfaces from the server. My main concern know is trying to make sure routing for NFS related IO goes over all these interfaces. Thanks again.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem - I have a few of that switch's ancestors and they seem to behave once the config is set.  Let me know if you run into any strangeness.